# How to print only specific class value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 div's in a View. Every div has unique single_value. so when i click on any of that it should alert that data value. For that i used the following script

```
  $(document).on('click','.single_school',function(){
      var school = $( ".single_school" ).attr('data-value');
        alert(school)
      });
```

But the problem is i'm only getting the first value whatever div I clicked on. How do i print only the specific div I clicked on.

Here is the View:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="single_school" data-value="1">
        <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>        
        <div class="school_info">
            <p class="school_name">ABC</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="single_school" data-value="2">
        <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>        
        <div class="school_info">
            <p class="school_name">XYZ</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="single_school" data-value="3">
        <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>        
        <div class="school_info">
            <p class="school_name">PQR</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `single_food`?

Comment: `single_food != single_school` @SaravananN

Comment: That was typo single_school should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','.single_school',function(){
  var school = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(school)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery `data()` to fetch the value when clicked on the element. And secondly you should use `$(this)` to get the current element value and not the classname. In your code, it would always give one result because you are using `$( ".single_school" )`. This should be replaced with `$(this)`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.single_school', function() {
  var school = $(this).data('value');
  alert(school)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="single_school" data-value="1">
    <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="food_info">
      <p class="school_name">ABC</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="single_school" data-value="2">
    <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="food_info">
      <p class="school_name">XYZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="single_school" data-value="3">
    <div class="selection_area choosen_school">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="food_info">
      <p class="school_name">PQR</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```